# Google geocode location result differs from maps result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a address in Germany 
**Deutschland, 13086 Berlin, Caligariplatz 1**

If I search for *"Caligariplatz 1"* directly in maps it shows the right location.
[https://www.google.de/maps/place/Brotfabrik/@52.552605,13.430414,17z][1]

If I use the geocode function from the api
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=13086%20Berlin,%20Caligariplatz%201][2]

The formatted address in the result is **13086 Berlin, Deutschland** without the street. The location is wrong. The location_type is only APPROXIMATE

Is it possible that some streets are not known by the geocode Database?

It's not the only problem. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things first:

- The geocoder is not a general purpose map/location search. It specifically tries to determine a position for an address. It is therefore inherently different to a search on Google Maps, which for example also supports searches like "parks in Berlin". [Also, the data used by the Geocoder might be different](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences).
- [Addresses should be formatted according to the conventions of the local postal service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat). Your address should be formatted "Caligariplatz 1, 13086 Berlin"

Now for your particular address, Google Maps finds it because there is a Place with that address. You could actually find this location with the Places API.

The address itself does not appear to be in the database, as you can for example confirm with [MapMaker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker). Since this is a square and not a traditional street, the building in question should probably be edited to include the address.